# Get Field Collection Array From Field Collection ID

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using the following code to return array of **all** field collection IDs for a node's field collection. How do I use these IDs to get an array of the values of the fields **within** the field collection?

```
case 'field_collected_dates':
$fid = field_get_items('node', $node, $key, $node->language);
$return[ $key_clean ] =  $fid;
break;
```

Answer (score -1):

this is how you can get values from field collection

```
if(isset($node->field_field_collection['und'])) {
  foreach($node->field_field_collection['und'] as $field){
    $colection_node = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($field['value']));
    $name_from_collection = $colection_node[$field['value']]->field_field_name['und'][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

now you can understand how to get value from field collection try to fix this in your code

THANKS

Comment: this does not answer my original question: "Get Field Collection Array From Field Collection ID"